# Remove SCSS and other unnecessary files before or after deployment?

Tags: heroku, sass, web-deployment

I am wondering what to do with SCSS files during deployment of my web app (though this generally applies to anything that can be compiled and needs to be cleaned up before deployment)

I've read that the SCSS files are useless as they are compiled into CSS before I deploy.

I'm using heroku and I could easily run a post-install script that removes the SCSS folder after deployment.

I'm wondering if this is the best practice though?

As an alternative, I'm thinking I could create a new deployment Master branch were I do all necessary cleanup from the development Master, and only deploy?

Is there another way? What's the most common method?

Answer (score 2):

You want to keep your source .scss files because that is where you should make changes in the future. As for the compiled .css files, those are expendable, because you can rebuild the .scss to create them again.

It is common for projects to contain two directories:

- `src` directory that contains all of the source files for developing the project (this directory is more permanent and it's common to use version control tools like `git` to keep a history of the development).
- `build` directory that contains all of the compiled and minified files and dependencies necessary to deploy a working version of the project (this directory is temporary, and its only purpose is to be deployed to production, or in your case, heroku).

For your `.scss` and `.css` files, you could have a directory in `src/scss` and a directory `build/css` (if you have multiple stylesheets), or you could simply have `build/index.css` if everything is in a single stylesheet.

It is common to automate the process of converting things from the `src` into the `build` directory using build tools/scripts to run a sequence of various tasks such as downloading dependencies, compiling and minifying files, and saving the final build artifacts in `build` dir.

Popular build tools include:

- Bower
- Gulp
- webpack
- make
- bash

For instance, with `gulp`, you can define a task that uses `'gulp-sass'` to target files in `src` that end in `.scss` and compile them into `.css` and save them in the `build` directory.